# how to add the functionality where the delete button should change to undo (for 10 secs) on click of which the item is not deleted

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, onclick, undo-redo

[complete code in stalkbiltz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-bmqg1t?file=src%2FApp.css,src%2FApp.jsx,index.html&terminal=dev)

**it will be very helpful if you can point me in the direction
I want to add a timmer when clicking the delete button timer should count down for 10 seconds delete button should change to undo (for 10 secs) on the click of which the item is not deleted**

```
      *<ul>
        {items.map((item) => {
          return (
            <li
              key={item.id}
              style={{ textDecoration: item.done ? "line-through" : null }}
            >
              <Checkbox
                onClick={() => onChangeBox(item)}
                defaultChecked={item.done}
              />
              {item.value}{" "}
              <button
                className="del-button"
                onClick={() => deleteItem(item.id)}
              >
                ❌
              </button>{" "}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `useState` hook and then check its value.

Create it:

```js
const [isUndoButton, setIsUndoButton] = useState(false); // you can name it however you want
```

Then in the `deleteItem` function change its value:

```js
function deleteItem(id) {
    // your code
    setIsUndoButton(true);
    setTimeout(() => setIsUndoButton(false), 10000); // 10000 ms = 10 seconds
}
```

And the button:

```js
<button className="del-button" onClick={() => deleteItem(item.id)}>
{ isUndoButton ? 'Undo' : '❌' }
</button>
```

**EDIT**

Setting only specific button text to `Undo`:

```js
const [isUndoButton, setIsUndoButton] = useState({});
```

```js
function deleteItem(id) {
    // your code
    setIsUndoButton((prev) => ({ ...prev, [id]: true }));
    setTimeout(() => setIsUndoButton((prev) => ({ ...prev, [id]: false })), 10000);

}
```

```js
<button className="del-button" onClick={() => deleteItem(item.id)}>
{ isUndoButton[item.id] ? 'Undo' : '❌' }
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying but this is only changing the text from  '❌' to  'Undo' that too just for 10 sec when 1. when 1st item is been added 2. when in a list of items an item's  delete button is clicked it will delete that item and change he text from  '❌' to  'Undo' for all the delete button

Comment: @banzawarrior Can you clarify the problem? What do you expect? And also, what do you mean in the first point?

Comment: I think isUndoButton, is a common flag that should be specific for each item just like id as when we click the❌ button undo text appears on all the buttons for the task added in the list

Comment: @banzawarrior Ok. I edited the answer. Note that you will need to wait 10 seconds before deleting the item (you can move that code in timeout) because you won't be able to see and click that undo button.

Comment: I found the ways, undo is not functional but I have something - https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-vbaxdg?file=src%2FApp.jsx

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Cart = () => {
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);
  const [deletedItem, setDeletedItem] = useState(null);
  const [undoTimer, setUndoTimer] = useState(null);

  const deleteItem = (item) => {
    // Remove item from cart
    const updatedCart = cartItems.filter((cartItem) => cartItem.id !== item.id);
    setCartItems(updatedCart);

    // Set deleted item and start undo timer
    setDeletedItem(item);
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      // If timer expires, remove the deleted item
      setDeletedItem(null);
    }, 10000);
    setUndoTimer(timer);
  };

  const undoDelete = () => {
    // Restore deleted item to cart
    setCartItems([...cartItems, deletedItem]);
    setDeletedItem(null);

    // Clear the undo timer
    clearTimeout(undoTimer);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      // Clear the undo timer when component unmounts
      clearTimeout(undoTimer);
    };
  }, [undoTimer]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Cart</h2>
      <ul>
        {cartItems.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            {item.name}
            <button onClick={() => deleteItem(item)}>Delete</button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      {deletedItem && (
        <div>
          <p>{deletedItem.name} deleted from cart</p>
          <button onClick={undoDelete}>Undo</button>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```